# I can't solve this basic equation?

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative

I need to make either $y$ or $x$ the subject of this equation but I can't seem to get either one

$\frac{2x}{1+x^2+y^2}+ \frac{1}{\sqrt2} =0$

I always end up with

$-2\sqrt2x-1-x^2=y^2$ which is obviously not going anywhere...

Comment: subject of the equation meaning?

Comment: To solve for $y$, extract roots (there will be zero, one, or two solutions depending on what $x$ is).  To solve for $x$, you might consider the quadratic formula.

Comment: @PerelmanJr $x=f(y)$ or $y=g(x)$

Comment: Isnt it already in that form?

Comment: "which is obviously not going anywhere..."  Why is that obviously going nowhere?  $y =\pm \sqrt{-x^2 - 1 - 2\sqrt {2} x}$ with the requirement that $-x^2 - 1 - 2\sqrt {2} x \ge 0$.  Why do you think that is "nowhere"?

Comment: @fleablood for some reason I thought I couldn't root it because it was a negative. Cheers!

Comment: You can't root it if it is negative.  But $-x^2 - 1 - 2\sqrt 2 x$ isn't nesc neg.  It could be positive if $x$ is negative and $2\sqrt 2 x \le -x^2 - 1 \le -1$.  $-x^2 - 1 - 2\sqrt 2 x \ge 0$ can be solved by the quadratic equation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that

$$x^2+2\sqrt2x+1+y^2=0\iff (x+\sqrt 2)^2+y^2=1.$$ This is the equation of a circle with center $(-\sqrt 2,0)$ and radius $1.$

We have $$y=\pm\sqrt{1-(x+\sqrt 2)^2}$$ and $$x=-\sqrt2\pm\sqrt{1-y^2}.$$

Comment: I'm not looking for solutions, I'm looking to make $x$ or $y$ the subject

Comment: This does both, don't they?

Answer (score 2):

What is wrong with seeing it as a quadratic in $x$ or $y$ and feeding it to the quadratic formula?  The simplest is $$y=\pm\sqrt {-x^2-2\sqrt 2 x -1}\\
y=\pm\sqrt{1-(x+\sqrt 2)^2}$$
which shows $x$ must be in the range $[\sqrt 2-1,\sqrt 2+1]$

Answer (score 1):

> $-2\sqrt2x-1-x^2=y^2$ which is obviously not going anywhere...

Why do you say that?

It looks to me like that is "obviously" going to

$y = \pm \sqrt{-2\sqrt 2 x - 1 - x^2}$

which can be solved by the quadratic equation to:

$y = \pm \sqrt{ - (x - \frac {2\sqrt 2 - \sqrt{8 - 4}}{-2})(x - \frac {2\sqrt 2 + \sqrt{8 - 4}}{-2})}$

$y = \pm \sqrt{-(x + \sqrt 2-1)(x+\sqrt 2 + 1)}$

As $-(x + \sqrt 2-1)(x+\sqrt 2 + 1)$ must be greater than or equal to zero we must have  $-1 -\sqrt 2 \le x \le 1- \sqrt 2$.

....

But perhaps simpler would be noting that $y^2 + x^2 + 2\sqrt {2} x + 1= 0$ is

$y^2 + x^2 + 2\sqrt{2}x + 2 = 1$ so

$y^2 + (x+\sqrt 2)^2 = 1$

So this is the graph of a circle and expressible as either $y = \pm \sqrt{1- (x+\sqrt 2)^2}$ or as $x = -\sqrt 2 \pm \sqrt{1 -y^2}$